# Does edittext hint count as actual text

Tags: android, android-edittext, conditional-statements, string-length, hint

I have an editext with a hint which displays `0`. My question is would `mEdit.getText().toString().length() == 0` be true or false in this configuration. Is the text in the hint treated as actual text in the textbox, hence returning a length of `1` or is it treated as something else and I would get `0`?

Comment: hint is just an imaginary text nothing else. when you touch it will disappear.

Comment: Hint is not counted as text

Answer (score 1):

If your `EditText` is empty, it will return `0`. Hint is not counted, because you are getting text which `EditText` field contains, not what hint contains.

To get hint length, use `mEdit.getHint().toString().length()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hint text is a place holder for the EditText. when you get mEdit.getText().toString().length() it returns length of text of your EditText not hint length of your EditText. and in your case its returns 0 because there is no any text in EditText.